# Helper-command not working after importing NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, helper

I discovered the phenomenon that always I enter the command

```
from nltk import *
```

the help command is not working anymore. I get the following error message then:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Does anybody has an explanation for that phenomenon?

I am writing code in Visual Studio in Python 3.

Thanks and best wishes,
Marcus

Comment: Importing `*` for nltk is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, importing `*` from nltk is a bad idea. You pollute your namespace with many variables that are unknown/unclear to you.

```
$ python

# Native Python variables.
>>> vars()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> len(vars())
4

# After importing from *
>>> from nltk import *
>>> len(vars())
510
```

Next in Python, modules are not callable but functions are.

From https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

> If you quit from the Python interpreter and enter it again, the definitions you have made (functions and variables) are lost. Therefore, if you want to write a somewhat longer program, you are better off using a text editor to prepare the input for the interpreter and running it with that file as input instead. This is known as creating a script. As your program gets longer, you may want to split it into several files for easier maintenance. You may also want to use a handy function that you’ve written in several programs without copying its definition into each program.
>
> To support this, Python has a way to put definitions in a file and use them in a script or in an interactive instance of the interpreter. Such a file is called a module; definitions from a module can be imported into other modules or into the main module (the collection of variables that you have access to in a script executed at the top level and in calculator mode).
>
> A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended. Within a module, the module’s name (as a string) is available as the value of the global variable **name**.

Looking at the `nltk.help` module:

```
>>> from nltk import help
>>> type(help) 
<type 'module'>

# A module is not callable. 
>>> help() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

# A module contains definitions and statements.
>>> dir(help) 
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_format_tagset', '_print_entries', 'brown_tagset', 'claws5_tagset', 'load', 'print_function', 're', 'upenn_tagset', 'wrap']


# A function is callable. 
>>> type(help.brown_tagset)
<type 'function'>
>>> help.brown_tagset()
(: opening parenthesis
    (
): closing parenthesis
    )
*: negator
    not n't
,: comma
    ,
--: dash
yada yada
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related, but if your plan is to import all of nltk, just use `import nltk`. No need for the `*`

Looking at the nltk.help module, you would need to use one of the functions defined there. As nltk.help itself is not a function but a library location.

See: https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html?highlight=help#module-nltk.help

So if that is the module you want to use, try:

`import nltk
nltk.help.upenn_tagset()`